# Plotly Markers takes some space from xaxis and my requirement is to start markers from origin (0,0)

Tags: javascript, plotly

When I use markers in plotlyjs. it take some space from (0,0) points. I want to make graph always from origin(0,0).

You can find working example here to reproduce this issue with markers.

Comment: link to show example: https://codepen.io/vijaythapak/pen/vQWGZE

Answer (score 0):

You’ll need to set the xaxis.range. On type: 'category' axes like yours each category is mapped to an integer starting from 0. So setting xaxis.range: [0, x.length - 1] where x is your x-coordinate array, should do the trick.

Please refer below url for more info.
https://community.plot.ly/t/make-plotly-always-show-the-origin-0-0-when-making-the-plot-in-plotly-js/15796